# jQuery Mobile Complex Listview Items

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I've got an iOS app that has some fairly complex UITableViewCells.

I'm considering converting it to a web app, and I'd like to use jQuery Mobile, if possible, since it seems a good way to have the app appear decently for desktop browsers, too. (iUI, while nice, REALLY doesn't work with IE, in my experience.)

The basic listview in jQuery Mobile appears to be exactly what I'd like to have, but I can't figure out a way to make each listview item any more complex than, say, multiple lines of text.

Ideally, I'd like the ability to have multiple `<div>` elements to structure text in a specific way, plus the ability to change the background color of each item to one of a list of pre-specified colors (we already have the color scheme and I can't change what each color means). Additionally, I'd like to keep the icon on the right-hand side to indicate that the user can click/press/tap the cell to see more detailed information.

Sample layout for how I'd possibly structure the HTML (it would actually be more complex than this):

```
<div>
    <div>
        Doe, Jane (57 y)
    <div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div>I: 0800</div>
        <div>R: 0900</div>
        <div>S: 1000</div>
        <div>O: 1100</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            // Some more content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can jQuery Mobile do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can add divs to the listview, but you can have multiple lines of text like this: [jquery mobile list formatting](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html) (View the source for a how to). You can also theme each li element in a different color: [jquery mobile theming list](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-themes.html).

My experience is that jquery mobile does not give you much freedom in customizing listviews, so if you need them to be more complex then the examples they have on their page, i would recommend using plain old html/css. Hopefully someone with more experience can prove me wrong!

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate, but that's pretty much what I've discovered as well. Thanks!